# Is 70% isopropyl alcohol still inflammable after 24h?

Tags: safety, heat, alcohols

I was wondering if Isopropyl can still produce flames after being vaporised on wood and having a day to evaporate plus rinsed with hot water afterwards? If I put heat on the wood (around 50 degree Celsius) after all this, do I still have a change of burning it or should it be fine?

Answer (score 0):

The [autoignition temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature) of isopropyl alcohol is about [400°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol). So given that there's no flame or spark, a temperature of 50°C would not suffice to ignite it.